# Exporting WKB (geometry) to .txt using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, export, well-known-binary

How can I export WKB (geometry) to text file using arcpy (ArcGIS)?

When I use the examples that I found on the Internet, it doesn't work. Below it's the code I'd wrote:

```
## Import arcpy module

import sys
import string
import os
import arcpy

## Global variables:

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")

IN_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
OUT_Addre = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
OUT_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

## Set progressor
lines = arcpy.GetCount_management(IN_FC)
number = int(fc.getOutput(0))

arcpy.SetProgressor("default","Exporting WKB geometry",0,number,1)

## for row in input
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(IN_FC, ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKB"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: 
## First feature
        elem = IN_FC.getFeatures().next()
        geom = elem.geometry()

## Export into wkb format
        wkb = geom.asWkb()

## Import to ogr geometry
        from osgeo import ogr
        geom_ogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(wkb)

## Import to Shapely geometry

        from shapely.wkb import loads
        line = loads(wkb)
        ls = wkb.encode('hex')

## output

        output_file = open(OUT_Addre & OUT_Name & ".txt", 'w')
        output_file.write('\n' & ls.encode('utf-8'))
        output_file.close()
```

Some errors message:

> import ogr or wkb = geom.asWkb() "doesn't exist"

Comment: Luke, I added the whole code I tried to write.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SHAPE@WKT` to get the geometry in text form. `WKB` is a binary format.

If you specifically need `WKB` serialized to a string, then you should look at any of the ways in Python to convert type `bytearray` to `string`. You could write the object to hexadecimal values:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(IN_FC, ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKB"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: 
        wkb = row[1]
        output_file.write(wkb.encode('hex') + '\n')
```

Then the question becomes why don't you just serialize the geometry with a common GIS format. You mention shapefile and WKB in the comments, so some more specific information about the software that needs this input could help. If shapefile is a valid format, you could just do:

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (in_FC, 'out.shp')
```

In your example you have a `for row in cursor` iterator combined with a `.next()`. You don't need both. The iterator will advance to the next row for you. If you only needed the first feature then you could use `next` without the iterator.

Comment: WKB *could* be exported as hexadecimal or base64 strings, but that wouldn't be a GIS question.

Comment: Marc, I've already used SHAPE@WKT, but the type of geometry description I need is in WKB format. After that I will have to insert in another sowftware.

Comment: Vince, I didn't even know this format until I needed to use it in other software that the shapefile input is by this format (WKB).

Comment: But the WK in WKB and WKT stands for "well known"!

Comment: Thanks Marc for your answer. Well, this software is EPANET and, to my knowledge, it uses background QGIS. So, my demand was to convert the polyline geometry to text file to import into this EPANET.

Comment: I was looking at EPANET last week. It looked like I could take the hydraulic network data from SDE, export to shapefiles with ArcMap, then with QGIS and GHydraulics plugin load the shapefiles to convert to EPANET .imp file for analysis. But I have not tried it.

Comment: @Marc, the final code was this:

import sys
import string
import os
import arcpy
import binascii

IN_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
OUT_Addre = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
OUT_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(IN_FC, ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKB"]) as cursor:

# saida
    for row in cursor:
        wkb = row[1]
        output_file = open(OUT_Addre + os.sep + OUT_Name + ".txt", 'a')
        output_file.write(binascii.hexlify(wkb) + '\n')
        output_file.close()

Answer (score 1):

My final code was:

```
# Import arcpy module

import sys
import string
import os
import arcpy
import binascii

# Global variables:

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")

IN_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

OUT_Addre = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

OUT_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(IN_FC, ["OID@", "SHAPE@WKB"]) as cursor:

# output
    for row in cursor:
        wkb = row[1]
        output_file = open(OUT_Addre + os.sep + OUT_Name + ".txt", 'a')
        output_file.write(binascii.hexlify(wkb) + '\n')
        output_file.close()
```